# creating dynamic content for application with multiple languages

Tags: angularjs, translation, multiple-languages

I have an `angular` application that is growing fast! This means that the application soon will have about 3 or 4 different languages. While this is a good thing there is one issue that i can't help wonder how to fix:

All static content such as

- Menu points
- Headers
- Notifications

Ect. Are easy to just translate into a new language (using a language file).

However content that is created by administrators and added to the system dynamicly wont be as easy in different languages.

For the purpose of understanding let me create an example:

The company is Netflix in its early days where only the US were able to access it. The whole application was in english and every time a movie was added the description, title, run time ect was in english.

Now the company goes international starting in Denmark.  Allowing viewers in Denmark to view movies.

But since the title, description and more are stored in a database when the danish viewer attempts to view the information about the movie it is not translated.

In the above case. How do you take something from  a database and make sure it is translated into the right language. Do you have to manually translate everything and add it to the file or is there a better way?

It seems so redundant that there must be a better way.

Comment: I think the language parameter/header should be part of the REST API. Then return the data with the language specific title and descriptions.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for your answer but do you add columns to your database that has the different attributes in other languages and just continue you expand that as you expand your range of languages?

Comment: Thats a question for the domain model architecture. If you want to support languages dynamically I'd add the translation into it's own table and have entries for each language and translation-id.